# How to use an enumeration in an XNA ContentReader?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, xna

For instance, I was thinking of replacing this:

```
var.StringAttribute = input.ReadString();
```

With something like this:

```
var.EnumAttribute = input.ReadExternalReference<EnumName>();
```

However this doesn't work *quite* right. And ideas on how to get input to read a custom enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

[`ReadExternalReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198588.aspx) Reads a link to an external file - that's not what you want to do.

If I understand you correctly, you want to read a string, and [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) it as an enum.

Try this:

```
string value = input.ReadString();
var.EnumAttribute = Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumName), value);
```

Note that this will work for both numbers (anything within the range of the enum's underlying type - typically `Int32`) and string values, but will throw an exception for invalid values.